# CURSOR vs variavel do tipo table

Tags: sql, sql-server, desempenho, tsql

Estou frente uma daquelas situações em que preciso executar uma ação para cada linha resultante de uma consulta.

Desta forma eu tenho duas opções, utilizar um `Cursor` ou uma `Table Variable`, porém as duas me parecem bem semelhantes (semanticamente).

Gostaria de saber se utilizando uma `Table Variable` vou conseguir alguma melhoria no desempenho em relação ao `Cursor`.

Acredito que a diferença entre os dois, é que a `Table Variable` irá realizar apenas uma consulta e percorrer os registros em memoria, enquanto que o `Cursor` irá realizar uma consulta (`Fetch`) para cada linha, mas não tenho como confirmar (este meu achismo).

Então qual dos dois é melhor e o por que?

**EDIT**

Resolvi adicionar um exemplo completo e as estatisticas.

**TABELA**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CursorTeste](
    [CursorTesteID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Coluna1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Coluna2] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Coluna3] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CursorTeste] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CursorTesteID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**INSERT**

```
DECLARE @count int;
SET @count = 0;

WHILE (@count < 10000)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CursorTeste VALUES (NEWID(), NEWID(), NEWID());
    SET @count = @count + 1;
END
```

**CURSOR**

```
DECLARE @coluna1 uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @coluna2 uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @coluna3 uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @CURSOR_teste CURSOR;

SET @CURSOR_teste = CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT Coluna1, Coluna2, Coluna3 FROM CursorTeste

OPEN @CURSOR_teste
WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM @CURSOR_teste INTO @coluna1, @coluna2, @coluna3;
    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0)
    BEGIN
        BREAK;
    END

    PRINT '{ ' + cast(@coluna1 as varchar(50)) + ' } - { ' + cast(@coluna2 as varchar(50)) + ' } - { ' + cast(@coluna3 as varchar(50)) + ' }';
END

CLOSE @CURSOR_teste   
DEALLOCATE @CURSOR_teste
```

**Table Variable**

```
DECLARE @coluna1 uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @coluna2 uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @coluna3 uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @indice int
DECLARE @count int
DECLARE @tabela table(
    RowNumber int identity,
    Coluna1 uniqueidentifier not null,
    Coluna2 uniqueidentifier not null,
    Coluna3 uniqueidentifier not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (RowNumber)
);

INSERT INTO @tabela
SELECT Coluna1, Coluna2, Coluna3 FROM CursorTeste

SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(RowNumber) FROM @tabela)
SET @indice = 1;
WHILE (@indice <= @count)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @indice = RowNumber + 1,
        @coluna1 = Coluna1, 
        @coluna2 = Coluna2, 
        @coluna3 = Coluna3
    FROM @tabela 
    WHERE RowNumber = @indice

    PRINT '{ ' + cast(@coluna1 as varchar(50)) + ' } - { ' + cast(@coluna2 as varchar(50)) + ' } - { ' + cast(@coluna3 as varchar(50)) + ' }';
END
```

[image: ESTATÍSTICAS DO CLIENTE]

- Avaliação 1: CURSOR
- Avaliação 2: CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
- Avaliação 3: CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
- Avaliação 4: WHILE LOOP WITH @TABLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cursores vs Tabela em memória

Cursores são quase sempre sub-ótimos em relação ao desempenho, mas há exceções e dependendo do caso pode não ser significativo para o seu problema.

Em todos os testes dos quais participei que envolviam cursores, nunca vi uma situação onde eles foram melhores em desempenho, mas há relatos na internet que dizem o contrário para situações bem específicas. Exemplos [aqui](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/comparing-cursor-vs-while-loop-performance-in-sql-server-2008/) e [aqui](http://www.sqlnotes.info/2011/12/21/are-cursors-bad-in-perfromance/).

Notei que você evitou alguns dos problemas ao declará-lo com `FAST_FORWARD`, pois permite ao SQL Serve traçar um plano mais otimizado para a leitura dos dados.

O principal problema da tabela em memória é o uso não moderado da memória, o que acaba limitando o número de registros que podem ser processados por execução.

## Sobre seu teste de desempenho

Através do seu teste de desempenho detalhado, é possível notar que não haverá um ganho real de desempenho entre as duas soluções para este caso em específico. É como dizer o óbvio, com tantos detalhes.

Então, use a forma que seja melhor para você dar manutenção no código. Neste aspecto o cursor ganha um pouco, pois o código é mais compacto e intuitivo.

A diferença de desempenho entre as duas soluções pode ser insignificante se a operação que você faz em cada linha consumir muitos recursos. As duas soluções podem ser inadequadas num contexto desses.

## Quando puder use uma consulta única

Sempre que puder dê preferência para *queries* que operem sobre o conjunto de dados e não sobre cada linha individualmente.

Por exemplo, imagine que temos as tabelas `A`, `B` e `C` e queremos inserir um registro em `C` para cada relacionamento entre `A` e `B`. Poderíamos então criar uma query da seguinte forma:

```sql
INSERT INTO C (C1, C2)
SELECT A1, B2
FROM A 
JOIN B ON B.FK = A.PK
```

Comment: entendo todo o problema dos Cursores e que o mesmo deve ser evitado e raramente isto não é possível. Mas a ideia aqui é comparar estas duas abordagens e ver se é possível obter algum ganho ao usar uma table ao invés de um CURSOR. inclusive adicionei algumas informações a pergunta, aparentemente o loop sobre uma table é bem semelhante ao CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD, quando analisando as idas ao servidor, os bytes recebidos e o tempo de execução.

Comment: @TobyMosque Entendo. Se puder fazer um favor, pois estou sem um ambiente com SQL Server aqui, execute o teste novamente sem o comando `PRINT` e poste o resultado novamente. Abraço.

Comment: atualizei a imagem.

Comment: @TobyMosque Muito bom. Parece que a Microsoft otimizou bastante os cursores FAST_FORWARD. Foi um pouquinho melhor do que acessando os registros em memória. Um detalhe é que não precisaria fazer o *count* dos dados se usasse o `@@ROWCOUNT` como [exemplificado aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1578248/1683070).

Answer (score 2):

Como muita gente já disse aqui muitas vezes: **você só deveria tentar resolver problemas de performance conhecidos.** E problemas potenciais de performance (aqueles ainda não conhecidos mas suspeitos de virem a aparecer) podem bem ser simulados antecipadamente, daí você terá um problema conhecido para resolver.

De qualquer modo, no seu exemplo usando variável do tipo *table* você executa uma consulta para preencher a variável e depois mais uma consulta para cada linha carregada para esta variável. Enquanto usando cursor você executa uma única consulta e depois percorre o resultado desta consulta linha a linha.

**Considerando seus exemplos, devido à quantidade de operações, utilizar cursor terá no mínimo a mesma performance, tendendo a ser menos custoso e com menor tempo de resposta do que usando variável do tipo *table***.

Mas veja que existem outras opções ao cursor além desta que você propôs. Por exemplo: se a consulta original retornar uma coluna de valor exclusivo, como um id, ou se se retornar um conjunto de colunas que juntas possam idenficar cada registro de maneira exclusiva, você pode repetir a consulta original no loop alternando este identificador exclusivo em vez de preencher previamente uma variável *table*.

Além disso, **só use loops se não houver outra solução além processar linha a linha o resultado da consulta**. De outro modo, o SQL Server é especializado em ligar tabelas, ler e processar grandes conjuntos de registros de uma só vez. O servidor sempre fará isso com melhor performance do que usando múltiplos comandos e do que usando cursores. E quando um único comando acabar demandando uma lógica impossível, você ainda pode utilizar tabelas temporárias para dividir a lógica do processamento em partes sendo que cada parte atuará sobre uma grande massa de registros de uma vez.

Caso seja necessário a atualização de milhões de linhas de uma vez, daí talvez seja necessário processar em lotes (tipo, 200 mil linhas de cada vez) pois o arquivo de log (que é usado para manter transações em andamento) pode estourar o espaço em disco. Mas tudo isso pode ser verificado em testes prévios.

Comment: entendo todo o problema dos Cursores e que o mesmo deve ser evitado e raramente isto não é possível. Mas a ideia aqui é comparar estas duas abordagens e ver se é possível obter algum ganho ao usar uma table ao invés de um CURSOR.